# How to 'jump' to a method in Java without linking back to where it was called from?

Tags: java, mips

I call a method from my main class, and when a particular condition is met, I have that method call itself with updated parameters. When I have the method call itself, I don't need it to come back to where it was called from. In other words, there's no need to have a "stack" of method calls - each method call can take the place of the previous method's call on the stack.

To make my point clearer, when using MIPS assembly language, we use jump (j) and jump-and-link (jal). I want my method call to be like a jump and not worry about coming back to its caller. I figure this might save some time/improve performance.

This is the relevant section of my code:

```
if (temp.contains(names[index]))
{
    System.out.println(names[index]);
    if (index < 13)
    {
        index++;
    }
    parse(i, bigLine, index);
}
```

This conditional block is in my parse method and I am calling parse from itself but I don't want it to come back to the caller. Would really appreciate any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: Seems like a premature optimisation to me... if it's even possible, which I don't think it is (at least not without some trickery)

Comment: If you're trying to do this sort of optimization, you'd get better performance out of an entirely different programming language.

Comment: As already stated there is no goto keyword in Java. You could create a conditional and use "return" or possibly break; I believe some consider this bad programming practice, though. I think you will find that in higher level languages this is going to be very trivial because of the overhead of a given function call anyway, though.

Comment: In theory the JIT compiler could perform this optimization for you.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, yes, a good JIT will eliminate the tail-calls here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's called tail recursion optimization, and no, Java doesn't support it. Other JVM languages (such as Scala) do, but in plain Java, if you need this optimization, you need to  do it by hand, by using iteration instead of recursion. In your case, it would look something like:

```
while (index < 13 && temp.contains(names[index])) {
    System.out.println(names[index]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was already told, this isn't possible in Java. You don't have a goto, so your only possibility is to do method calls and that's where the stack comes into play.

But don't worry, you're also completely wrong in your "I figure this might improve performance" guess. In Java, we do optimization the correct way: analyze the performance, identify the bottlenecks and remove or bypass those bottlenecks. That way you don't have to "figure" anything, you'll have cold hard facts to show you what you need to do.

I recommend that if you intend to keep on working with Java, you don't try to project other programming languages onto it. This is especially the case with assembly language, although you might like to work with the bytecode itself, if you're looking to go that low level.